# Create Firebase User on ios without auto-signin

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

i'm writing an ios-app with firebase as backend.
In my app, there are some admins, who should be able to create new users. A new user should not be able to create an account on his own.

On web, i'm using the function

```
ref.createUser({
        email: ctrl.user.email,
        password: ctrl.user.password
    }, function(error, userData) { // }
```

with a random password and reset the password afterwards. So the user will receive an email with a password reset link and can set a new password and log in after that. After creating the user, i'm storing all relevant userdata to the database.

On ios i'm trying to create a new user with:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (user, error) in }
```

But if I do it this way, I'm signed out with my admin-account and logged in with my fresh created account. Due to this, I'm not able, to store the userdata to the database, because this is restricted to admins....

Is there a way on ios to only create an user, without to auto-signin with this user?

Best wishes

Tobi

**EDIT**
I've written an AWS lambda function with the firebase admin sdk for node.js and create the user inside the function and trigger the function via a webservice-call from my ios-app.
Not perfect, but working....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, calling `createUser(withEmail:, password:)` will log in a new user. To achieve what you are trying to do, I recommend a workaround by doing something like this (assume that currently an Admin is logged in):

```
// Create the values
var email = alreadySelectedUserEmail
var password = arc4random_uniform(1000000) // or another random number

// Send the information to the database
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user_data").child(email) .
        setValue("lorem ipsum") // or another value

//  THEN create the user, AFTER sending the data
        // This will automatically log you in to the new account
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email,
        password: password) { (user, error) in
    // Check for any errors
    if let error = error {
        print error
    } else {
        // If there are none, LOG OUT…
        try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()

        // …and log back into Admin (with whatever login info they have)
        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: adminEmail,
                password: adminPassword) { (user, error) in
            // Check for any errors
            if let error = error {
                print error
            } else {
                // All done, new account created!
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have had a similar idea, but how do I get the adminPassword?

I could store it at the initial admin-login as a UserDefault-Value, but what, if the admin changes his password otherwise?

Comment: Now, I have written an AWS Lambda function with the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.JS and create the user with this over a webservice-call from the ios-app.